# How to disable Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can I disable bootstrap tooltip?
I enable it using:

```
function activateTooltip() {
  const toolTips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');

  toolTips.forEach(t => {
    new bootstrap.Tooltip(t);
  });
}
```

I'm using this function from the bootstrap .min file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to save the reference of the Bootstrap Tooltip and call  the [.disable()](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#disable) method.

```js
// Enable tooltip
const tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(yourElement);

// Disable tooltip
tooltip.disable();

// Enable tooltip again
tooltip.enable();
```